# remove audio come from speaker when using mic in godot

Tags: audio, audio-processing, godot4

I want to record audio voice of player with godot 4; i use audio server and record audio effect for that. my problem is that when mic is near speaker, the sound come from speaker also recorded, which I don't want to record it. how can this issue handled in godot?
I pass audio played inside game to record-bus to be included in file, but sound of speaker also recorded which makes Unpleasant effect.